# jquery: rotate items in loop

Tags: jquery

How would you make this slider navigation bar go in loop?

I made simple jquery that just increments margin, can you think of a way of easily looping this thing?

Right now if you click enough times it blank space will be visible...

Any help appreciated.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/utKqe/2/

```
//other category page, navigate through cats
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#otherleftarrow').click(function() {
            $('#othermenu ul').animate({marginLeft: '-=100px'}, 200);
            return false; // prevent default click action from happening!
        });

        $('#otherrighttarrow').click(function() {
            $('#othermenu ul').animate({marginLeft: '+=100px'}, 200);
            return false;
        });

    });
```

Comment: uuuuu lots of code you are missing. Check parent width, clone elements at start, dynamic slider position check... This can be achieved easely if you plan to have fixed `li` widths (I won't suggest to). Otherwise there's lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite nice jQuery plugin for this task: [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel).

[Circular carousel example](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_circular.html).

You can easily use it for your purpose.

Comment: Isn't this too complicated for such a simple task?

Comment: If it seems too heavy - you can just look into source and see how "circular" part made. But if you need it to just work - this solution may be the best.